# Merging variables in Ansible with roles

Tags: ansible

I'm configuring my environment via the following:

inventory.yml

```
all:
  children:
    production:
      1.2.3.4
    staging:
      1.2.3.5
```

In group_vars/all.yml  I'm setting up a hash of users which will be added in a playbook.  I'd like to be able to add users specifically to group_vars/staging.yml that would be merged with the same setting in my group_vars/all.yml.

Is there a proper way to merge the hash or declare an inheritance in this case?

Comment: Fix the inventory. The keyword ``hosts:`` is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [*DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). Quoting

> *"This setting controls how variables merge in Ansible. By default, Ansible will override variables in specific precedence orders, as described in Variables. When a variable of higher precedence wins, it will replace the other value. Some users prefer that variables that are hashes (aka ‘dictionaries’ in Python terms) are merged. This setting is called ‘merge’. ..."*

For example, given the inventory and *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    production:
      hosts:
        1.2.3.4
    staging:
      hosts:
        1.2.3.5
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
users:
  admin:
    shell: /bin/bash
  ansible:
    shell: /bin/sh
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/production/users.yml 
users:
  dealer:
    shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/staging/users.yml 
users:
  tester:
    shell: /bin/bash
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: users
```

by default overrides the dictionaries. Gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [1.2.3.4] => 
  users:
    dealer:
      shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
ok: [1.2.3.5] => 
  users:
    tester:
      shell: /bin/bash
```

When *ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR* is set to merge the dictionaries the playbook gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook pb.yml

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [1.2.3.4] => 
  users:
    admin:
      shell: /bin/bash
    ansible:
      shell: /bin/sh
    dealer:
      shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
ok: [1.2.3.5] => 
  users:
    admin:
      shell: /bin/bash
    ansible:
      shell: /bin/sh
    tester:
      shell: /bin/bash
```

This setting will be [deprecated](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) in 2.13.

Quoting the **Deprecated detail**

> *"This feature is fragile and not portable, leading to continual confusion and misuse"*

Quoting the **Deprecated alternatives**

> *"the combine filter explicitly"*

For example, rename the common users' dictionary to *users_all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
users_all:
  admin:
    shell: /bin/bash
  ansible:
    shell: /bin/sh
```

Then the filter [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) merges the dictionaries

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: users_all|combine(users)
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [1.2.3.4] => 
  users_all|combine(users):
    admin:
      shell: /bin/bash
    ansible:
      shell: /bin/sh
    dealer:
      shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
ok: [1.2.3.5] => 
  users_all|combine(users):
    admin:
      shell: /bin/bash
    ansible:
      shell: /bin/sh
    tester:
      shell: /bin/bash
```

Note: To merge lists see the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530698/6482561).